# Translate emoji code points to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, github, github-api, emoji

I'm attempting to load emojis from [the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/emojis/) and convert the code point(s) to a string in JavaScript. This works fine for emoji comprised of a singe code point but fails for those comprised of multiple points, eg `family_woman_woman_girl_girl`. I'm using [zero width joiner (zwj)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) to concatenate the characters.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('emojis');
const zwj = '\u200D';

async function renderList() {
  // load the github emojis: https://developer.github.com/v3/emojis/
  const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/emojis');
  const data = await response.json();
  
  // render a list item for each emoji
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    // skip GitHub's custom emoji
    if (!/\/unicode\//.test(value)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    // parse the url into an array of code points
    const codePoints = value
      .substr(57)
      .replace(/\.png\?.*$/, '')
      .split('-')
      .map(hex => parseInt(hex, 16));
    
    // translate the code points to a string. SOMETHING WRONG HERE
    const emoji = codePoints
      .map(p => String.fromCodePoint(p))
      .join(zwj);
    
    // render the list item
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `${key}: ${codePoints} ${emoji}`;
    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}

renderList();
```

```html
<ul id="emojis"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all emoji sequences are glued together with ZWJ. Most notably, people and their skin tone are simply combined without any filler.

Unicode maintains [a list of all code points/combinations](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/) it considers an emoji. The `emoji-data.txt` file are all single-cp emojis. `emoji-zwj-sequences.txt` are all sequences featuring at least one ZWJ and `emoji-sequences.txt` the rest.

Note, that not all cps in `emoji-zwj-sequences.txt` are glued together with a ZWJ as well, e.g., this line:

```
1F469 1F3FD 200D 1F4BB                      ; Emoji_ZWJ_Sequence  ; woman technologist: medium skin tone                           #  8.0  [1] (‍)
```

The `artist` part is added with a ZWJ. The woman and skin tone parts are joined without any other cp.

There are some heuristics how to find out, if you need a ZWJ or not. If you look towards the end of `emoji-data.txt` you see, that the skin tone modifiers have the property `Emoji_Modifier`. Those are defined as simply changing the appearance of a previous emoji, if it has the `Emoji_Modifier_Base` property.

Also the next block, `Emoji_Components`, can be combined in one way or the other without a ZWJ.